# Checking if the content of a dictionary is True

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary(names) with other dictionarys inside. My task is to look for an specific key and if the content that key is True.

```
hermes = {"Español":True, "Ingles":True, "Chino":False, "Frances":False, "Italiano":True}
jose = {"Español":True, "Ingles":False, "Chino":False, "Frances":False, "Italiano":True}
lupe = {"Español":True, "Ingles":True, "Chino":True, "Frances":False, "Italiano":True}
nacho = {"Español":False, "Ingles":True, "Chino":False, "Frances":True, "Italiano":False}
luis = {"Español":False, "Ingles":False, "Chino":True, "Frances":True, "Italiano":False}
names = {"Hermes":hermes, "José":jose, "Lupe":lupe, "Nacho":nacho, "Luis":luis}
x = input("Ingrese el idioma requerido: ")
for postu in names:
  for k,c in names[key].items():
    if k == x and c==True:
      print(postu)
```

Whenever i run the program nothing happens after it asks me the input. I've tried to just print k and c to see if the key and contents dont appear but it works perfectly. My problem happens trying to check if c is True.

Comment: I think you need nested dict here.

Comment: `for k,c in names[key].items():` should be `for k,c in names[postu].items():`

Comment: From where `key` is coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't define `key` anywhere, so I'm not sure what that's trying to do.  If you're trying to print all the people who speak the inputted language, that would be more like:

```
x = input("Ingrese el idioma requerido: ")
for name, speaks in names.items():
    if speaks[x]:
        print(name)
```

Or you could get the names as a list by doing:

```
x_speakers = [name for name, speaks in names.items() if speaks[x]]
```

Comment: `speaks.get(x)` would be better

Comment: Only if you don't want to raise an exception when the inputted language is invalid!  It's not necessarily "better" to silently avoid errors.